# DRF checkpoint with crossvalidation fails with error "ERRR: _weights_column: Weights column '__internal_cv_weights__' not found in the training frame"

Tags: h2o

Tried on 28.0.2 and latest 30.0.1 versions.

Create first DRF:

```
rf1 <- h2o.randomForest(
  model_id="first_drf1_x1",
  x = f2,
  y = r1,
  training_frame = train1,
  validation_frame = valid1,
  ntrees = 49,
  nfolds = 5,
 seed = 1
)
```

Train it and they try to continue training from this model like this:

```
rf2 <- h2o.randomForest(
  model_id="second_drf1_x2",
  x = f2,
  y = r1,
  training_frame = train2,
  validation_frame = valid2,
  ntrees = (49+50),
  nfolds = 5,
  checkpoint = "first_drf1_x1",
  seed = 1

)
```

Immediately in logs this can be seen:

```
POST /3/ModelBuilders/drf, parms: {model_id=second_drf1_x2, validation_frame=RTMP_sid_aea1_16, response_column=pcs7_e_dt_4010u, training_frame=RTMP_sid_aea1_14, seed=1, nfolds=5, ntrees=99, ignored_columns=["ts","leve_batch_nbr"], checkpoint=first_drf1_x1}
04-30 10:20:34.601 127.0.0.1:54321       55804  FJ-1-5    INFO: Creating 5 cross-validation splits with random number seed: 1
04-30 10:20:34.612 127.0.0.1:54321       55804  FJ-1-5    ERRR: _weights_column: Weights column '__internal_cv_weights__' not found in the training frame
```

When the first model created, there are 5 CV models created and they have that internal field set like this:

```
“_weights_column":"internal_cv_weights",
```

but when main first model is trained then :

```
Building main model.
...
“_weights_column":null,
```

I've opened a bug in h2o jira, but maybe somebody already has seen this issue and have a workaround.
If nfolds set to 0 (disabling cross validation) - then everything works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have `nfolds` disabled. As the [docs](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/checkpointing-models.html) say "Cross-validation is not currently supported for checkpointing."

If you are using new data, it may not make much sense to start from an old model for DRF. The old/original trees (1-49) won't benefit from the additional observations from the new data. The new trees after the checkpoint (50-99) will have the additional observations. So half your trees will be lacking some predictive info which can create some bias in your scoring.

Comment: Thank you! That note in the documentation I've missed. Though, weird that in GBM it works (at least doesn't through an error and trains model)